# Count of RelatedLIsts on a Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, related-list, bestpractice

Using Tooling API, or Reports, is there a way to find how  many related lists are on each Page Layout ?

I am dealing with a large Org with more than 600 Objects, and some objects have more than 100 page layouts, with many related lists.

I used the following Query to get the count of Page Layouts on each object

```
SELECT TableEnumOrId, count(Id) FROM Layout WHERE ManageableState='unmanaged' group by TableEnumOrId
```

Looking for a similar Query or any other approach to get the counts of related lists on each pagelayout as Optimizer Report did not give that detail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like the UI API is your best bet here. It has an endpoint for **[`related-list-info`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_related_list_object.htm)** that should do the trick. Definitely easy to pull the results in Workbench. Would be straightforward enough to parse via Apex as well if need be. You could even write a batch to aggregate all the results and save somewhere on platform, send them out as an email, etc.

```
GET /services/data/v53.0/ui-api/related-list-info/Account
```

Note that you can also pass `recordTypeId` as a query string parameter.